# How to use Higher Rank Trait Bounds with anonymous closure in return type

Tags: generics, rust, higher-rank-types

Is it possible to return `FnMut` closure that takes reference and return reference with same lifetime as it takes?

```rust
fn fun(buf: &mut [f32], mut idx: usize) -> impl FnMut(&[i16]) -> &[i16] {
    |input| {
        buf[idx] = input[0] as f32;
        idx += 1;
        &input[1..]
    }
}
```

I've tried things like `impl for<'a> FnMut(&'a [i16]) -> &'a [i16])` and it gives

```rust
error[E0482]: lifetime of return value does not outlive the function call
 --> src/main.rs:1:44
  |
1 | fn fun(buf: &mut [f32], mut idx: usize) -> impl for<'a> FnMut(&'a [i16]) -> &'a [i16] {
  |                                            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  |
note: the return value is only valid for the anonymous lifetime defined on the function body at 1:13
 --> src/main.rs:1:13
  |
1 | fn fun(buf: &mut [f32], mut idx: usize) -> impl for<'a> FnMut(&'a [i16]) -> &'a [i16] {
  |             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The returned function should capture `buf` by value (i.e., use `move`)
- The returned function must not outlive `buf` (having the lifetime `'buf` in the below snippet):

So:

```
fn fun<'buf>(buf: &'buf mut [f32], mut idx: usize) -> impl FnMut(&[i16]) -> &[i16] + 'buf {
    move |input| {
        buf[idx] = input[0] as f32;
        idx += 1;
        &input[1..]
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you point to a docs or clarify youself what `+ 'buf` means in this context? Why it's not just `&'b [i16]`?

Comment: @user1685095 `+ 'buf` means that the returned function must not outlive the lifetime `'buf`.